# SpamAssassin custom rule that runs shell command

Tags: linux, spamassassin

I've been reading on SpamAssassin for some time now and learned a lot but I cannot seem to figure out a way I cannot find a way to create a rule where a 3rd party script can be executed to for a custom rule.
THis would have to be something user based not globally.

I want to run additional verifications on domains and email addresses.

I wish to build a reputation system in which if a domain or email address are checked against the contacts list and other things.

I have have considered modifying the profile to add regex rules but that seems like a way to complicated way of doing it. A more preferred scenario would be to simply run a 3rd party script that returns the score for each domain and email address.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, SpamAssassin has no such facility, but since you ask on a programming site, I assume you are not alien to writing some code on your own.

The plugin facility in SpamAssassin was designed for this sort of thing. You can create a piece of Perl code which gets called for each message which SpamAssassin analyzes, and you have access to everything Perl has access to.

In particular, look at the [pyzor plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/spamassassin/tags/spamassassin_release_3_4_0/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin/Pyzor.pm?revision=1567124&view=markup) which calls an external program and returns its analysis results to SpamAssassin. There's a fair amount of boilerplate there, but the part you need to start with is getting the right arguments to the `helper_app_pipe_open` call (on line 282 as of version 3.4.0, which is what I link to above). These things are configurable so you could perhaps even just reconfigure the path to `pyzor` to your own program as a proof of concept. Note that it needs to accept a `check` argument and some other parameters, and a message from a temporary file on its standard input.

[Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin.pm](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/spamassassin/tags/spamassassin_release_3_4_0/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Plugin.pm?revision=1567124&view=markup) contains POD documentation for the plugin API. Other files in the module tree contain useful documentation too; in particular, you might want to refer to the general documentation in [Mail::SpamAssassin.pm](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/spamassassin/tags/spamassassin_release_3_4_0/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin.pm?revision=1567124&view=markup) and [Mail::SpamAssassin::Conf.pm](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/spamassassin/tags/spamassassin_release_3_4_0/lib/Mail/SpamAssassin/Conf.pm?revision=1567124&view=markup) to understand the configuration parameters you can pass to your plugin.

Comment: What about adding a rule with a call to exec something? I am trying to get this done as a user config thing in order to not require any change done to SA.

Comment: Then why do you post to a programming site?  But anyway, I'll repeat the idea to use the `pyzor` plugin but make it call your own checking tool instead. You'll probably need some wrapping to make it behave like the `pyzor` plugin expects, but it should not be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, there is a new [TxRep](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/TxRep) plugin that automatically recognizes senders you've seen recently.  There is also a collection of [whitelist and blacklist options](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html#whitelist_and_blacklist_options).

If you wanted to implement something yourself, I think you'll quickly find that an `exec` mechanism won't scale well.  Perhaps try crafting your own [DNSBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) instead.  This can be done with custom code and any DNS server (e.g. bind, dnsmasq, etc) or with a DNS server designed for this purpose, such as [RBLDNSD](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/rbldnsd.html).  The SA wiki on [DnsBlocklists](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists) has directions for how to hook it into SA.

Usually, people seeking this kind of solution don't have DNSBLs configured properly.  I'd take a look into that before trying to build your own project.